# Android view re-creation on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I want to do something like in iPhone development: reposition controls manually without recreating the whole view.
what are pros and cons of this approach?

Comment: Does it mean that you want to show different layout when orientation changes?

Comment: well, I want to re-organize all the controls when layout is changed. I know i can create 2 different layout for portrait and landscape, but I'm wondering what problems willI get repositioning control myself...in other words, should I do this myself, or should I create 2 layouts and take care of saving/restoring app's state, and all the background threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will be useful for somebody.

if you don't want ro re-create your view on orientation change, the only thing you need is to change corresponding Activity in manifest file like this:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
```

if you want to reposition controls manually, override onConfigurationChanged and reposition everything you need there

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // reposition and/or hide/show controls here
}
```